# How to add Document with Custom ID to firestore jetpack compose kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there any chance to add a document to firestore collection with custom generated id, not the id generated by firestore engine?

in Kotlin jetpack compose android development how you would do it?

Comment: This question has been asked a few times before. So please check the duplicate to see how you can solve that.

Comment: i didnt find my answer in kotlin jetpack compose kotlin did you find ?

Comment: Adding a custom document id instead of the one that is generated by Firestore, is not an issue related to Jetpack Compose.

Comment: you didnt understand my question i want to choose what is the id of the document, and I want to know the latest and the best syntex and the best way to write it in jetpack compose kotlin I couldn't find that on the web

Comment: it is simular questions but the answer they give him not relevant for 2022 anymore they are not the best syntax for today date there is a shorter way to do it

Comment: Generating a document ID is not related in any way to UI techniques.

Comment: so can you please help me edit my question to get the answer I want please?

Comment: Have you even tried the solution in the duplicate answer?

Comment: yes i have tried it and it didn't work I can upload a youtube for you to see in a private message if you want dolev146@gmail.com

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Most likely you should post another question in which you show us what you have tried.

Comment: because in android development there are two threads and I need to know how I can change to a different thread so that I don't pause the UI thread

Comment: Kotlin jetpack compose